# Republish a Google Workspace Marketplace app

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace-add-ons

We have a Google Sheets add-on from the Google Workspace Marketplace. There is a hate review, we report that, but the marketplace did anything. So we are thinking of re-publishing the add-on. So my questions are:

- If we un-publish the add-on and publish it again, will all the previous reviews be removed?
- How could we keep the name of the add-on during the whole process of un-publishing and publishing?

Comment: If you unpublish and republish the app you'll have the same name, installations and reviews. Please report your issue at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191597.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Does it mean that unpublishing and republishing the app will keep the same url (our current url is [this](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/formula_editor/599355229197))? After unpublishing the app, if we publish it with another name, all the reviews will be removed?

Comment: If you unpublish and republish the URL will be the same. If you change the name of the URL will change slightly to reflect the new name, but the other than nothing will change (same id, same installs, same reviews).

Comment: I think I could 1) unpublish the old add-on to release the name of the add-on; 2) then create a new standard Google Cloud Platform project with the name. As a result, the new project will have a new id, new installs and new reviews. What do you say? @AlejandroTamalet

Comment: Basically you are creating a new app. You can do that if you want, but why go so far because of a bad review?

Comment: @AlejandroTamalet Thank you. I wanted to understand how the whole review/marketplace works; previously it was not me who published that…

Answer (score 1):

Official documentation below:

- [Publish an add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/publish-add-on-overview)
- [Overview: Publish an app](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/how-to-publish)

Does not indicate whether to unpublish and publish the Add-on again would remove the review.

As instructed by another community member:

> "... If you unpublish and republish the app you'll have the same name, installations and reviews ..."

Leaving the option of the Add-on removal to achieve the review deletion not viable.

An alternative to this would be to report the review as instructed [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9281422?hl=en#:%7E:text=Rating%20and%20review%20policies) under 'Rating and review policies' based on 'Offensive content' as it states:

> "... Reviews that violate the following policies will be removed ..."

AND

> "... Google will remove content that contains obscene, profane, or offensive language or content. ..."

Another alternative was provided by the same community member to submit an issue report [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191597) so it can be reviewed internally by the Google Team.